# How to convert bathroom ceiling exhaust fan to a ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan, exhaust-fan

I'd like to remove a bathroom exhaust fan and in it's place install a small ceiling fan for better circulation.  This bathroom does have a window that opens so I'm not concerned about code nor moisture.  It's a large bathroom and my wife would like a small ceiling fan in it for helping to cool it down on hot days when she's putting on makeup/drying her hair, etc and it would help circulate the air conditioner air.  The ceiling our high 14' in this room.  Can I use the electrical for the ceiling fan that is used for the exhaust fan (there is no light associated with the current exhaust fan).

Thanks.

Comment: the electrical? yes. the box? no. sounds like a bad idea to me, fwiw...

Comment: Ceilings are 14 feet high at the location of the exhaust fan?

Comment: You know those fans do different things right? The exhaust fan removes (as in physically evacuates) humidity and stench from the bathroom.  Ceiling fans simply stir the air already in the room, which brings heat down from the ceiling but never exchanges the air.  They could be highly effective together, but you really do need that exhaust fan.  Without it expect condensation, mold and rot damage.

Comment: Yes, ceiling is 14' high and the exhaust fan is on the ceiling.  No need to have air exhausted through the fan in that room because there is a window in the room that opens which is plenty of ventilation for air - no mold issues too big of a room, never steams up.  What I'm after is to have a ceiling fan to circulate air to help for the hot days when we are grooming; putting on makeup, etc - an exhaust fan is of no help.  Not to bring down heat, but just like in other rooms in the house where ceiling fans are installed.

Comment: Add a thru-wall fan or window fan and leave your exhaust fan,

Comment: Jeff Cates .... can't do that.  CC&R's don't allow.   I not only want the function of air circulating via a ceiling fan, as it does in the bedroom; I also want it for the  aesthetics since this is a very large bathroom - double vanity, etc.    I think we've got it covered now.   And since the window in this room opens to allow air  and the weather is such that mold/moisture is never an issue, (mirror never fogs) I'm good to go.